# I'm trying to alert "70" and "John" but instead, I'm getting an alert "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to alert "70" and "John" but instead, I'm getting an alert "[object Object]". I'm not sure why.

```
<p>
<script>
var Car = function(maxSpeed, driver) {

  this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  this.driver = driver;

}

var myCar = new Car(70, "John");
window.alert(myCar);
</script>
</p>
```

https://js.do/code/244719

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.alert(myCar.maxSpeed+"and"+ myCar.driver);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringfy`

```js
var Car = function(maxSpeed, driver) {

  this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  this.driver = driver;

}

var myCar = new Car(70, "John");
window.alert(JSON.stringify(myCar))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to set what the object should show when called as a string by setting the `toString` method.  It's not necessarily advised unless you know what you're doing, but the example is suitable:

```js
var Car = function(maxSpeed, driver) {

  this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  this.driver = driver;
  this.toString = () => [this.maxSpeed,this.driver].join(' and ')
}

var myCar = new Car(70, "John");
window.alert(myCar);
```